# What is a rooted tree?

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree

What does it mean to build a rooted a tree? I read the definition in [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RootedTree.html) but even if we assign a node to be the root, why does the tree take only the shapes below? I mean I can draw a rooted tree with 4 vertices in more that the 4 shapes below? Right?

[image]

Comment: What additional shape can you draw?

Comment: I was thinking of just changing the orientation from left to right.. are you hinting that it's the same whether I change direction or flip graph upside down?

Comment: Well, "same enough" to not make a real difference (depends on context of course). This is called isomorphism. You can turn the graph upside down, but it is still the same graph (for some definition of same).

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RootedTree.html

Comment: Alright I got it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only difference is that one node in the tree is a special start node.

Normally, trees are recursive; all tree nodes are themselves trees. A 'rooted tree' is just one where the child nodes are marked differently from a special parent. That may mean that an algorithm can't be implemented recursively, or has some special condition for dealing with the root node.

The example that comes to mind is a red-black tree. Nodes in a red-black tree are either labelled red or black. But there is a special rule that "the root node is always black". So that's a special treatment we must apply to the root, and only the root. Children of the root node could be red; that means the 1st-level children of the root node cannot be treated as root nodes in their own red-black tree.

So you might expect 'distinguishing' code like

```
 if(node.isRoot):
    node.Color = black
```

An free tree would be any node in a binary search tree; it doesn't matter which node you pick, operations like find and insert always work the same. Their algorithms are recursive. Algorithms over free trees never include a question like 'is it the root node.'